# app burns numbers into iPad screens, how can I prevent this?

Tags: ios, ipad, graphics, screen

**EDIT: My code for this is actually open source, if anyone would be able to look and comment.**

Things I can think of that might be an issue: using a custom font, using bright green, updating the label too fast?

The repo is: https://github.com/andrewljohnson/StopWatch-of-Gaia

The class for the time label: https://github.com/andrewljohnson/StopWatch-of-Gaia/blob/master/src/SWPTimeLabel.m

The class that runs the timer to update the label: https://github.com/andrewljohnson/StopWatch-of-Gaia/blob/master/src/SWPViewController.m

**=============**

My StopWatch app reportedly screen burns a number of iPads, for temporary periods. Does anyone have a suggestion about how I might prevent this screen persistence? Some known workaround to blank the pixels occasionally?

I get emails all the time about it, and you can see numerous reviews here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stopwatch+-timer-for-gym-kitchen/id518178439?mt=8

Apple can not advise me. I sent an email to appreview, and I was told to file a technical support request (DTS). When I filled the DTS, they told me it was not a code issue, and when I further asked for help from DTS, a "senior manager" told me that this was not an issue Apple knew about. He further advised me to file a bug with the Apple Radar bug tracker if I considered it to be a real issue.

I filed the Radar bug a few weeks ago, but it has not been acknowledged. Updated radar link for Apple employees, per commenter's notes rdar://12173447

Comment: Screen burning on iOS devices? I've never seen that, and I frequently have the same thing displaying on a device for ages (I'm a developer; when an app is running in the debugger it doesn't screen lock, and I often forget about one when I go for a meeting or whatever). Do you see the same thing on more than one device?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue myself, but I have had dozens of reports, so I assume it's not BS. If you Google for iPad screen burn, you can also see similar reports.

Comment: Maybe changing a color would be enough :)

Comment: Image persistance on LCDs is not uncommon. Those people reporting the issue with your app should go back to apple and get a replacement as they have a faulty display.

Comment: 1) Nobody outside of Apple can look at Radar, so posting that massive link at the bottom of your question is useless.  2) For the benefit of those people *inside* Apple and viewing your question, you can use a URL of the form "`rdar://1234567`" where those numbers are actually the bug ID.  One of my own Radar bugs is, for example, "'rdar://8111675'" (edited my comment because StackOverflow doesn't know - nor needs to care - about the "rdar" URL scheme).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann hehe, seems SO doesnt parse custom URL schemes properly

Comment: @AndrewJohnson Not sure if I can help but I noticed similar problems on my iPads when using CoreAnimation and the CADisplayLink. I eventually changed my code to avoid said combination and surprisingly,... no more afterburners :)

Comment: @wasabii My code is actually open-source, I will put links in the question. Would you have a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a "burn in" on a non-CRT display, but there can be an image persistance/retention issue on some LCD display panel types.

One way to avoid both is to very slowly drift your image around, much more slowly than a screen saver.  If you move your clock face around a small amount and very slowly (say several minutes to make a full circuit of only a few dozen pixels), the user may not even notice this happening.  But this motion will blur all fine lines and sharp edges over time, so even if there is a persistance, the lack of sharp edges will make it harder to see.

Added:
There is also one (unconfirmed) report that flashing pixels at the full frame rate may increase the possibility of this problem.  So any in-place text/numeric updates should happen at a more humanly readable pace (say 5 to 10 fps instead of 30 to 60 fps), if repeated for very long periods of time.  The app can always update the ending number to a more accurate count if necessary.

Comment: Interesting, I might have to try this. It would make a good plog post if it works!

Answer (score 1):

"Burn in" is due to phosphor wearing in CRTs. LCDs cant have burn in since they dont use phosphor.

More likely it is image retention/[Image Persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_persistence). An image can remain 'stuck' on the screen for up to 48 hours. Usually it shouldnt last that long so it may be a defect in their hardware too. MacRumors has a thread about [iPad image retention](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1220231), it discusses this very issue. As for a solution, there is nothing you can do about the actual screen because its a just how LCD's work. What I would try if you are still concerned is using more subtle colors. Unless something is actively changing the pixels (think screen saver) you arent going to be able to completely eliminate the problem.